# Fastest way to call a specific method through a decision

Tags: java, methods

i have a question for call management.

I get a message with a payload of 3 bytes in a `byte[]`. Different bits in there leads to calling another method. I did it with a logical AND between the byte and a shiftet 1 to get the value of the bit. I used if elseif etc. to call the specific method. Is there another possibilty to realise it, maybe a HashMap or something?

At least im forced to use max. Java 1.4

Greetings,
fnobbi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many different methods you are calling. If it's less than (I'm guessing here) 20, I would use simple bit-mask tests on a `int` (which is 4 bytes - use the lower 3) with `if()`.

For example:

```
public static void callMethod(byte[] bytes) {
    int bits = (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16 +
               (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8 + 
               (bytes[0] & 0xFF);
    if ((bits & 1) > 0) {
        methodForBit0Set(bytes);
    }
    if ((bits & 2) > 0) {
        methodForBit1Set(bytes);
    }
    if ((bits & 4) > 0) {
        methodForBit3Set(bytes);
    }
    // etc
}
```

If you're only calling one method then stopping, you'll want to use `elses` between the `ifs`, and may also want to order the tests in order of most-frequently expected first.

Using a hashmap wouldn't be *that* much faster than these extremely fast operations IMHO even if you have lots of tests, and this is easier to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: You need to mask the bytes to treat them as unsigned. The `bits` can be `int` as its only 24-bit.  If this is the pattern to search for I would search for the lowest bit set and switch on that value.

Comment: Why are you using long? Probably you meant to use int, since that is 4 bytes wide as you mentioned in the text. long is 8 bytes and overkill for the 3 byte message case...

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to also add the byte masking Peter Lawrey mentioned. If someone copy/pastes this code it could lead to some very unexpected results :)

Comment: You just need `b & 0xFF` to convert to unsigned.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `b & 0xFF`... Thanks, I must be tired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch, even in Java 1.4. The switchs can be nested where different bytes interact. I assume you don't have 16 million possible methods to call. (256^3)

Comment: Are you kidding? I'm assuming bit-masks... can you imagine the size of the table you'd need to cater for all combos???

Comment: Like I said, I assume you don't have 16 million different methods to call in which case, there must be some simplification which can occur.  You shouldn't have more than one case group per method.